# Page is reloading everytime I click on a tab-nav item. Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do a simple tab-nav with two tabs for my components, so far I implement te tabs like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#tabone"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-md"></i>&nbsp;DIGITALIZAR</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#tabtwo"><i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;ADJUNTAR</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content mt-2">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="tabone" role="tabpanel">
        <div [hidden]="hayParametrosEscaner" style="text-align: center;">
          <app-parametros-scanner (parametros)="onParams($event)" ></app-parametros-scanner>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!verVisor">
          <app-imagegallery #visorImagenes></app-imagegallery>
        </div>
        <div class="control-buttons">
          <button class="tolowercase" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect (click)="verImagenes()">{{escaneoExtra}}</button>
          <button class="tolowercase" [hidden]="!verVisor" [disabled]="enviandoArchivos" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect
            (click)="enviarAlServidorDesdeVisor()"> Enviar selección al
            servidor</button>
          <button class="tolowercase" [hidden]="verVisor" [disabled]="enviandoArchivos" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect
            (click)="enviarAlServidorDesdeFuente()"> Escanear y guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabtwo" role="tabpanel">
        TEST
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the browser it look like this:
[image]

But!!! the thing is that everytime I click on any of the tabs, the page is reloaded instead of changing tab. It's like the app were crashing and reloading or something, and I don´t know whyyyy.

Comment: `<a>` tag requires an `href`, and this will force the router to navigate. Try putting your **DIGITALIZAR** and **ADJUNTAR** in `<span>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: href being used rather than router causing a redirect